# user logged out after redirect in wp

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to logged in through wp function.

```
wp_set_current_user( $data['userid'], $user->data->user_login );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $data['userid'] );
        do_action( 'wp_login',$user->data->user_login);
```

and when i trying to redirect through wp function

```
wp_redirect(site_url().'/profile/');
```

it's become logged out

I am checking it through wp function as

```
is_user_logged_in()
```

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try `wp_signon` function instead of those you used. It takes credentials for first value:

```
$user = wp_signon( array (
  'user_login' => 'entered-login',
  'user_password' => 'entered-password',
  'remember' => true 
), false );

if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
    echo $user->get_error_message();
}
```